# My jquery code is conflicting with my links?

Tags: jquery

My jquery code is conflicting with  my links, causing them not to open in a new window "target=_blank"?

```
 onReady:function(){
          $('a').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            CookieControl.setConsent(true);
            CookieControl.closeAndHide();
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
          });      
 },
```

The affected links are `<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Link</a>`

Comment: this is because you're calling [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), which prevents the default action of the click event on all links.

Comment: When I comment out that line, the links on the website work but now they load in the parent window and new window

Comment: Please update your question with the code for one of the links.

Comment: Its just basic html links for e.g. <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Link</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing your callback does is cancel the event!

```
 event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than tying your event to all `<a>` tags, add a class to the link or links you wish to target, like so:

```
<a class="lnkSpecial" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Then bind your event to that class:

```
  $('.lnkSpecial').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      CookieControl.setConsent(true);
      CookieControl.closeAndHide();
      window.location = $(this).attr('href');
  });
```

This will prevent the default action only on the link or links with the class.